# Perl script searching in hash table

Tags: perl, hashtable

I have programmed a Perl script which has two input files:

1. The first file has on each line phrase and then a value between parentheses. Here an example:

   ```
   hello all (0.5)
   hi all (0.63)
   good bye all (0.09)
   ```
2. The second file has a list of rules. For example:

   ```
   hello all -> salut (0.5)
   hello all -> salut à tous (0.5)
   hi all -> salut (0.63)
   good bye all -> au revoir (0.09)
   good bye -> au revoir  (0.09)
   ```

The script has to read the second file and for each line it extracts the phrase before the arrow (e.g. for the 1st line: `hello all`) and it will check if this phrase is present in the first file (in our example here it is found).

If it is present it write the whole line `hello all -> salut (0.5)` to the output.
So in this example the output file should be:

```
hello all -> salut (0.5)
hello all -> salut à tous (0.5)
hi all -> > salut (0.63)
good bye all -> au revoir (0.09)
```

My idea is to put all the contents of the first file into a hash table.
For this here my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

my $vocabFile = "file1.txt";
my %hashFR =();
open my $fh_infile, '<', $InFile or die "Can't open $InFile\n";

while ( my $Ligne = <$fh_infile> ) {
  if ( $Ligne =~ /(/ ) {
    my ($cle, $valeur) = split /(/, $Ligne;
    say $cle; 
    $h{$cle}  = $valeur;
  }     
}
```

My question now: how do I extract the segment of word just before the arrow and search for it in the hash table?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to `use strict`. This would cause your program to fail when it encountered undeclared variables like `$InFile` (I assume you meant to use `$vocabFile`). I'm going to ignore those types of issues in the code you posted because you can fix them yourself once you turn on strict.

First, a couple of logic issues with your existing code. You don't seem to actually *use* the numbers in parentheses that you store as your hash values, but if you ever do want to use them, you should probably get rid of the trailing `)`:

```
    my ($cle, $valeur) = split /[()]/, $Ligne;
```

Next, strip leading and trailing whitespace before using a string as a hash key. *You* may think `"foo"` and `"foo  "` are the same word, but Perl doesn't.

```
$cle =~ s/^\s+//;
$cle =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Now, you're already most of the way there. You clearly already know how to read in a file, how to use `split`, and how to use a hash. You just need to put these all together. Read in the second file:

```
open my $fh2, "<", "file2" or die "Can't open file2: $!";

while (<$fh2>) {
    chomp;
```

...get the part before the `->`

```
    my ($left, $right) = split /->/;
```

...strip leading and trailing whitespace from the key

```
    $left =~ s/^\s+//;
    $left =~ s/\s+$//;
```

...and print out the whole line if the key exists in your hash

```
    print $_, "\n" if exists $hash{$left};
```

...don't forget to close the filehandle when you're done with it

```
close $fh2;
```

(although as amon points out, this is not strictly necessary, especially since we're reading and not writing. There's a nice [PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=902128) dealing with this topic.)

Comment: This is an incredibly nice answer. +1 all the way! Nitpick: closing isn't *that* neccessary, and `die !?` is a syntax error ;-) you meant `use autodie` or `die "Can't open file2: $!"`.

Comment: @amon Thank you, and fixed. That's what I get for using the answer box as my compiler ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $FILE_1, '<', shift @ARGV;
open my $FILE_2, '<', shift @ARGV;

my @file1 = <$FILE_1>;
my @file2= <$FILE_2>;

close $FILE_1;
close $FILE_2;
# Store "segments" from the first file in hash:
my %first_file_hash = map { chomp $_; my ($a) = $_ =~ /^(.*?)\s*\(/; $a => 1 } @file1;

my @result;
# Process file2 content:
foreach my $line (@file2) {
    chomp $line;
    # Retrieve "segment" from the line:
    my ($string) = $line =~ /^(.*?)\s+->/;
    # If it is present in file1, store it for future usage:
    if ($string and $first_file_hash{ $string }) {
        push @result, $line;
    }
}

open my $F, '>', 'output.txt';
print $F join("\n", @result);
close $F;

print "\nDone!\n";
```

Run as:

```
perl script.pl file1.txt file2.txt
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is a nice answer, but great answers also explain what they are doing, instead of dumping code. There are some issues with your code. One, you aren't using any error handling for `open`. I suggest to `use autodie` as a remedy. Two, your code is very inefficient. Instead of `push @result, ...`, you could print out that line directly!

Comment: @amon - yes obviously! It is not perfect, but it is not a "production" code too. It was just an example. My intention was to outline solution, focusing on retrieving data.

Comment: @amon - one more thing - if anything is not clear in my code feel free to ask! I thought it is almost self-documenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very straightforwardly by creating a hash directly from the contents of the first file, and then reading each line of the second, checking the hash to see if it should be printed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %permitted = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt';
  map { /(.+?)\s+\(/, 1 } <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;
  print if $permitted{$phrase};
}
```

**output**

```
hello all -> salut (0.5)
hello all -> salut à tous (0.5)
hi all -> salut (0.63)
good bye all -> au revoir (0.09)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your replie. I'am using now the Borodin's version (tahnks to him)  @Borodin: How can i change tu*o make it print the result in the text file use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
my $out = "result2.txt";
open outFile, ">$out" or die $!;
my %permitted = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt';
  map { /(.+?)\s+\(/, 1 } <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;
  print  if $permitted{$phrase};
}
close outFile;